# How can I automate the code below to run automatically when I receive an email?

Tags: vba, outlook, office-automation

How can I automate the code below to run automatically when I receive an email ?

This runs if I manually execute it but doesn't when I receive an email in "Auto-Woodgrain" folder.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Woodgrain()

    Dim ol As Outlook.Application
    Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
    Dim I As Object
    Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim at As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim dir As Scripting.Folder
    Dim dirName As String
    
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    Set ol = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set fol = ns.Folders("Auto-Woodgrain").Folders("Inbox")
    
    For Each I In fol.Items
    
        If I.Class = olMail Then
        
            Set mi = I
            
            If mi.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                'Debug.Print mi.SenderName, mi.ReceivedTime, mi.Attachments.Count
                
                dirName = _
                "\\emsfile1\Users Shared Folders\mmiller\Woodgrain\" & _
                Format(mi.ReceivedTime, "yyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss ") & _
                Left(Replace(mi.Subject, ":", ""), 10)
                
                If fso.FolderExists(dirName) Then
                    Set dir = fso.GetFolder(dirName)
                Else
                    Set dir = fso.CreateFolder(dirName)
                End If
                
                For Each at In mi.Attachments
                
                    'Debug.Print vbTab, at.DisplayName, at.Size
                    at.SaveAsFile dir.Path & "\" & at.FileName
                    
                Next at
                
            End If
            
        End If
    
    Next I

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the `NewMailEx` event of the `Application` class. This event fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Use the Entry ID returned by the string passed to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

Also you may consider setting a handle for the `ItemAdd` event of the `Items` class. That is if you are intersted in handling new items for a specific folder.